# I can't add item to ( std::vector < std::vector <std::string> > )

Tags: c++, linux

Why can't I add an item to vector :

```
std::vector < std::vector <std::string> > my_list;
my_list[0][0] = "this is text";

std::cout << "text: " << my_list[0][0] << std::endl;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you create a vector it is empty. ***All*** indexing into it will be out of bounds. Perhaps you should [get a good beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: You need to init all the vectors inside the vector of vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike some containers (such as `std::map`), a `std::vector` does not grow on demand.

So before you index an element you need to make sure the `std::vector` has the appropriate size. You can do that by passing a size on construction.

In your case you could use the flashy syntax

```
std::vector < std::vector <std::string> > my_list{{"this is a test"}};
```

to get things going.